# bash script that is run from Python reaches sudo timeout

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, sudo, sudoers

This is a long bash script (400+ lines ) that is originally invoked from a django app like so -

```py
os.system('./bash_script.sh &> bash_log.log')
```

It stops on a random command in the script. If the order of commands is changed, it hangs on another command in approx. the same location.

`ssh`ing to the machine that runs the django app, and running `sudo ./bash_script.sh`, asks for a password and then runs all the way.

I can't see the message it presents when it hangs in the log file, couldn't make it redirect there. I assume it's a sudo password request.

Tried -

- `sudo -v` in the script - didn't help.
- `ssh` to the machine and manually extend the sudo timeout in `/etc/sudoers` - didnt help, I think since the django app is already in the air and uses the previos timeout.
- splitting the script in two, and running one in separate thread, like so -

```py
def basher(command, log_path):
    with open(log_path) as log:
        Popen(command, stdout=log, stderr=log).wait()

script_thread = Thread(target=basher, args=('bash_script_pt1.sh', 'bash_log_pt1.log'))
script_thread.start()
os.system('./bash_script_pt2.sh &> bash_log_pt2.log') # I know it's deprecated, not sure if maybe it's better in this case
script_thread.join()
```

The logs showed that part 1 ended ok, but part 2 still hangs, albeit later in the code than when they were together.

I thought to edit `/etc/sudoers` from inside the Python code, and then re-login via `su - user`. There are snippets of how to pass the password using `pty`, however I don't understand the mechanics of it and could not get it to work.

I also noted that `ps aux | grep bash_script.sh` shows that the script is being run twice. As -

`/bin/bash bash_script.sh`

and as

`sh -c bash_script.sh`.

I assume `os.system` has an internal `shell=True` going on.

I don't understand the Linux entities/mechanics in play to figure out what's happening.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess should be your friend. But there's a discrepancy: on one hand you run it via *sudo*, on the other without. Be consistent.

Comment: If your script runs with sufficient privilege to modify the `sudoers` file then it does not need to modify the `sudoers` file.  And if it is run via a web service, then it absolutely should neither have nor seek such a level of privilege.

Comment: As John Bollinger indicated, you probably shouldn't be elevating the privileges of a web server to root.  That being said, in order to troubleshoot this, consider becoming the application server userid and attempting to run the command as that userid.   Does the script run?  Does sudo prompt for a password?   The userid executing the sudo command may need to be given permission to run without a TTY.  Also, with sudo, you can be very specific about which commands the user can run.  In order to avoid a larger security issue, limit the possible commands.

Comment: @CristiFati I assume the django app was started up with sudo. In the terminal, I saw that that allows to run sudo commands inside the script and not be prompted for a password again

Comment: But when you run it from *Python*, I assume you're not *root*, therefore some of the line might ask for credentials.

Comment: It's ran by the django app when I upload a patch, like an update mechanism

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the django app has different and more limited permissions, than the script itself does, and the script is inheriting said restrictions because it is being executed by it.

You need to find out what permissions the script has when you run it just from bash, and what it has when you run it via django, and then figure out what the difference is.